# Вид придаточного (присубстантивное/изъяснительное)

Tags: аспектология

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в данном случае придаточное будет изъяснительное или присубстантивное?

**В первый раз тогда поняв ясно,*что для всякого человека и для него впереди ничего не было, кроме страдания, смерти и вечного забвения*, он решил, что....**

Оно относится к деепричастию **поняв** или к опущенному существительному **мысль**?

Спасибо!

Comment: *придаточное будет изъяснительное или присубстантивное* - А почему "или"? Разве одно исключает другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Это **изъяснительное** придаточное, так как ЧТО является **союзом** (хотя союзные слова там тоже могут использоваться). В таких СПП **опорным словом** может быть как **глагол, так и существительное со значением речи**, поэтому нет необходимости в какой-либо замене.  Придаточное передает содержание  сказанного, но не определяет его.

Вот пример с существительным в качестве опорного слова: *В первый раз тогда поняв **(ту) мысль, что** для всякого человека...* ЧТО — союз.

2) В СПП с **присубстантивными придаточными**  (иначе говоря, это определительные придаточные) **союзы не используются**, там местоименная связь, например: *В первый раз тогда поняв  **(ту) мысль, которая** раньше была для него неясной.*  Здесь мысль – определяемое **существительное**, КОТОРАЯ – союзное слово.

Во всех случаях корреляты (указательные слова) **факультативны.**

Comment: *В СПП с присубстантивными придаточными (иначе говоря, это определительные придаточные) союзы не используются,* - Валгина категорически не согласна. Там все примеры - на присубстантивные изъяснительные придаточные - с союзами. http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-045.htm

Comment: Например: И все ясней и ясней становилась для него мысль, что существуют только три гордых призвания человека: наука, искусство и свободный физический труд (Купр.); Я ловил себя на мысли, что начинаю думать о конце войны (С. Бар.); Существует теория, будто бы искусство кино есть искусство режиссера; Плоская мысль, что писательство - легкое занятие, до сих пор колом стоит в мозгах многих людей (Пауст.); Через некоторое время, однако, в единственную гостиницу зелено-розового Рамздэля явился расстроенный, промокший Мак-Ку с известием, что его дом только что сгорел дотла (Наб.).

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, здесь просто нет причин предполагать наличие какого-то опущенного слова. Предложение и семантически, и грамматически вполне закончено. То есть придаточное относится к глаголу "понять" (в форме деепричастия) и таким образом является обычным изъяснительным придаточным.

Впрочем, как уже написал, противопоставление изъяснительных придаточных присубстантивным само по себе непонятно.

> Изъяснительная придаточная часть может быть и присубстантивной, однако
>   имена существительные, нуждающиеся в изъяснении, очень ограничены
>   своей семантикой. Это отвлеченные существительные со значением
>   восприятия, волевых и эмоциональных состояний, мыслительной
>   деятельности, речи и подобные (слух, сообщение, известие, заявление,
>   угроза, сознание, убеждение, уверенность, чувство, мысль и некоторые
>   др.), связанные происхождением или семантикой с соответствующими
>   глаголами и сохранившие способность к управлению.

Валгина, http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-045.htm

Так, в немного измененном предложении

*В первый раз тогда поняв ясно ту мысль, что для всякого человека и для него впереди ничего не было, кроме страдания, смерти и вечного забвения, он решил, что....*

придаточное будет *присубстантивным изъяснительным*.

(+) Тут возникли сомнения в последнем (моем) примере. Я немного изменю еще раз.

*В первый раз тогда поняв ясно простую мысль, что для всякого человека и для него впереди ничего не было, кроме страдания, смерти и вечного забвения, он решил, что....*

Здесь уже не должно быть сомнений в классификации придаточного как *присубстантивного изъяснительного.*

Comment: По-моему, в приведённом Вами примере надо бы убрать местоимение "ту". При его наличии придаточное скорее будет присубстантивным **определительным**, а не изъяснительным. Может, я и ошибаюсь...

Comment: @slava1947 Да?! Я экспромтом эту фразу родил, не задумывался. Но без "ту" фраза какая-то нерусская становится. А вот насчет того, что станет определительным, это как-то неожиданно. Спасибо, я подумаю.

Comment: Вдогон. А если вместо "ту" будет "простую (мысль)"?! Или "известную"? Неужели тоже определительное? Или выбор прилагательного/местоимения так влияет на тип придаточного? Не похоже как-то...

Answer (score 1):

Вместо комментария.

Я уже говорила раньше о **важности терминологии.** Если даются разные определения, то можно говорить об одном и том же и не понимать друг друга.

1) Автор вопроса, очевидно, пользуется более **современной классификацией**, а она выглядит немного иначе, чем у Валгиной, хотя и сходство, разумеется, есть.

2) Все СПП делятся на **две принципиально различные группы** (вероятно, типы): (1) нерасчлененной структуры с присловными придаточными и (2) расчлененной структуры (с присоставными придаточными, они относятся ко всему предложению, а не к слову).

Вторая группа – это преимущественно обстоятельственные придаточные, которые по структуре напоминают ССП.

Первая же группа неоднородна, здесь-то и возможны **варианты в классификации.**

3) Группу (1) делят **на три подгруппы**: собственно присловные, приместоименные и прикомпаративные.

Нас интересуют **собственно присловные (со знаменательными словами)**, так как туда относят присубстантивно-атрибутивные придаточные (**с определяемым** словом) и **изъяснительные** придаточные (с **изъясняемым** словом).

4) **Схема** присубстантивных СПП такова: **[±К + сущ.], (союзное слово).**

**Корреляты** (указательные слова): тот, такой, **союзные слова**: который, какой, чей, что, где, когда. Например: *Он произнес **такую** речь, **какой** позавидовал бы Демосфен.* В школьной классификации это **определительные** предложения, в которых опорным словом является **существительное**.

**Союзы** в таких предложениях возможны только **при двойном значении** (определение + следствие, сравнение, цель), например: В*етер поднял **такой** шум, **что** ничего не было слышно.   У неё было **такое** выражение лица, **будто** она знала что-то*.

5) **Схема изъяснительных** придаточных такова: **[изъясняемое слово ±К] (союз/союзное слово).**

Изъясняемое слово называют **опорным**, и это могут быть **разные части речи:** глагол, **существительное**, предикативное прилагательное. Тематика также разная: речь, мысли, желания, ощущения, эмоциональные состояния.

6) Таким образом, то, что у Валгиной называется **присубстантивно-изъяснительными** придаточными, в данной классификации это **изъяснительные** придаточные с опорным словам, выраженным **существительным**. *Я ловил себя **на мысли, что** начинаю думать о конце войны.* Это изъяснительное придаточное, ЧТО – союз.

7) Примечание

Есть еще один интересный объект: **СПП с приместоименно-изъяснительными придаточными** (это уже подгруппа приместоименных придаточных). Их еще называют **вмещающие СПП**. В школьной практике они соответствует объектным придаточным.

Они отличаются от обычных изъяснительных придаточных **более свободной тематикой** и наличием **обязательного коррелята (в роли дополнения**), например: *Весь день он бы занят **тем, что** ремонтировал машину.*

Надо сказать, что здесь могут использоваться **и обычные изъясняемые слова**, но с коррелятом, например: ***Мнение*** комиссии сводится **к тому, что** надо прекратить работы. Сравнить: ***Мнение, что*** надо прекратить работы, разделяли все члены комиссии.